# No such file or directory - Airflow

Tags: airflow, dbt

I have my airflow project with the structure as below

```
airflow
    |
    |----dags
    |      |----dag.py
    |
    |----dbt-redshift
             |----models
                   |----model.sql
```

I have included the dbt-redshift directory in the *volumes* section as

```
volumes:
  -./dbt-redshift:/opt/airflow/dbt-redshift
```

And I'm trying to run the dbt inside the DAG using a bash operator

```
 dbt_task = BashOperator(task_id='dbt', bash_command="cd ~/dbt-redshift && dbt run", dag=dag)
```

But when i execute the DAG i get the error

```
cd: /home/***/dbt-redshift no such file or directory
```

I'm not sure I understand how these directories are located inside the airflow project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting the volume inside the container to `/opt/airflow/dbt-redshift`, but the BashOperator references `~/dbt-redshit` with `~` resolving to `/home/airflow`.

(Assuming you are using the `apache/airflow` image)

Either change the command used by the BashOperator to reference `/opt/airflow/dbt-redshift` or change the volume to mount to the home directory.